# Twilio chat client is coming nil for iOS after getting token from twilio function

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I am trying to integrate Twilio chat (message, voice, and video) in my application.
I am not able to get chat client in the below code

```
 // Set up Twilio Chat client after getting token
    TwilioChatClient.chatClient(withToken: token, properties: nil, delegate: self) {(result, chatClient) in

    // Here chatClient is coming nil all the time and the result is not successful.

       self.client = chatClient

      }
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the `result` parameter and what it says? Is there an error message you are missing?

Comment: Error Domain=signal.sdk.domain.error Code=102 "Error validating token." UserInfo={kTCHErrorMsgKey=Error validating token., NSLocalizedDescription=Error validating token.

Comment: Cool, so that means that there is something wrong with the token you have generated. The issue isn't in your iOS app. So, what is the code you are using to generate the token? Can you check it looks like a valid token using https://jwt.io.

Comment: I am using Programmable Chat Token for generating the access token.
It's saying invalid signature.

Comment: Yup, and where are you generating that token from?

Comment: In the example code, there is one method getting the token from the URL
function name - retrieveToken
Github Link: https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift

Comment: Did you generate an example token from the Twilio console? Or did you set up a server as described here? https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift#setup-an-access-token-server

Comment: I have used Twilio console to generate URL using Programmable Chat Token.
Here is an example of that: https://********.twil.io/chat-token
I am using this link for example project setup
Github: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/chat-quickstart-swift

Comment: Ok, you're using a Twilio Function to generate your token? Great. Can you share the code you are using in the Function?

Comment: Here it is:
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  let appName = context.CHAT_APP_NAME;
  let identity = event.identity;
  let deviceId = event.device;

  let endpointId = `${appName}:${identity}:${deviceId}`;

  //pre-built in libraries to create a MessagingGrant
  let AccessToken = Twilio.jwt.AccessToken;
  let IpMessagingGrant = AccessToken.IpMessagingGrant;

  let ipmGrant = new IpMessagingGrant({
    serviceSid: context.CHAT_SERVICE_SID,
    endpointId: endpointId,
    pushCredentialSid: context.CHAT_PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID
  });

Comment: const accessToken = new AccessToken(
     context.ACCOUNT_SID,
     context.CHAT_TWILIO_API_KEY,
     context.CHAT_TWILIO_API_SECRET
  );

  accessToken.addGrant(ipmGrant);
  accessToken.identity = identity;

  callback(null, {token: accessToken.toJwt()});
};
Not able to add this in one comment. So, added seperately.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There seems to be something wrong with your token generation as you get an error when trying to instantiate the Chat client.

The code you're using to generate the token is mostly right, though a little out of date. We can use a `ChatGrant` now, rather than the `IpMessagingGrant` and there's no need to include an `endpointId` any more. I would update your function to:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let identity = event.identity;
  let AccessToken = Twilio.jwt.AccessToken;
  let ChatGrant = AccessToken.ChatGrant;
  let chatGrant = new ChatGrant({
    serviceSid: context.CHAT_SERVICE_SID,
    pushCredentialSid: context.CHAT_PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID
  });
  const accessToken = new AccessToken(
    context.ACCOUNT_SID,
    context.CHAT_TWILIO_API_KEY,
    context.CHAT_TWILIO_API_SECRET
  );
  accessToken.addGrant(chatGrant);
  accessToken.identity = identity;
  callback(null, { token: accessToken.toJwt() });
};
```

Also, I would confirm that you have correctly set the following environment variables in the function configuration: `CHAT_SERVICE_SID`, `CHAT_PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID`, `ACCOUNT_SID`, `CHAT_TWILIO_API_KEY` and `CHAT_TWILIO_API_SECRET`.

If any of those are missing or incorrect then your token will be invalid.

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Thanks, Phil. It's working now.
I do not know why that autogenerated Twilio function is not updated.

Comment: I'll follow up about that. Sorry it made this harder! If this did answer your question, would you mind accepting the answer so that others can see it helped? Thanks!

Comment: Please upvote this question as well. It will be helpful for others.

Comment: Sure. Btw, accepting the answer is the ✅ next to the answer.